# Get all item from a related Models in Django

Tags: python, django

I have Two models related:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    ----

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    ....
```

I have an instance of the class author. How can I get all articles of the author? Such as:

```
articles = author.article_set.getAllArticlesFromAuthor()
```

*I know it can be obtained from a query*, but I would like to know if exists a short method provided by Django

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking; that is what the article_set is already. Just do `author.article_set.all()`.

Comment: I read the docs and I dont find it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply way to do it, you can also handle it inside model of `Author` an example:

```
class Author(models.Model):

    def get_articles(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(author__pk=self.pk)

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    ....
```

return QuerySet of articles from specific author.

```
Author.objects.get(pk=1).get_articles()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a property

```
class Author(models.Model):
    # model fields

    @property
    def articles(self):
        return self.article_set.all()
```

so you can use it like

```
author = Author.objects.get(name="Author's Name")   # get Author
articles = author.articles                          # get articles by author
```